# Maplex not respecting feature weight in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, maplex, citrix

I have a bunch of unlabeled point features with a high feature weight (800) and a labeled street centerline file with a weight of zero. Despite setting the weights for conflict resolution my street labels still overlap the point features.

Has anybody experienced this in ArcMap 10.2.2 on Citrix VDI, and have a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

On my citrix VDI I have various file and database locations. For ArcMap there is a plugin called RouteSmart that we purchase as part of a bundle with ArcMap. RouteSmart has a config file that creates a file structure for it's use with specific locations for workspaces and system file geodatabases. If you work on an mxd outside of this directory (which I often do because RouteSmart impedes some of the data manipulation I do for cartographic production) Maplex will not recognize some properties for feature classes referenced in a RouteSmart workspace file geodatabase. I imported the feature class I wanted the labels to not overlap with into a file geodatabase outside of the RouteSmart file directory and the labels from the street layer no longer overlapped the point features.